# Why does the ResponseEntityExceptionHandler catch ONLY Generic Exception not specific run times

Tags: spring, spring-boot, exception, spring-rest

My Customized Response Entity is as below :

```
@ControllerAdvice
@RestController
public class CustomizedResponseEntityExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {

@ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
@ResponseBody
public final ResponseEntity<Object> handleAllExceptions(Exception ex, WebRequest request) {
logger.debug ("CustomizedResponseEntityExceptionHandler-Generic Exception caught !!  "+ex.getMessage ());
    EASExceptionNotifier exceptionResponse = new EASExceptionNotifier
    (new Date(), ex.getMessage(),request.getDescription(false));
    return new ResponseEntity(exceptionResponse,HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
}



@ExceptionHandler(InvalidRequestTypeException.class)
public final ResponseEntity<Object> handleInvalidRequestTypeException(InvalidRequestTypeException ex, WebRequest request) {
    EASExceptionNotifier exceptionResponse = new EASExceptionNotifier
    (new Date(), ex.getMessage(),request.getDescription(false));
    return new ResponseEntity(exceptionResponse, HttpStatus.NOT_ACCEPTABLE);
}
```

}

My Exception class is as defined below :

```
public class InvalidRequestTypeException extends RuntimeException {
private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(InvalidRequestTypeException.class);
private static final String ERR_DESC="Error desc: Invalid request type received ";

public InvalidRequestTypeException (String storeMetaData, String message) {
    super (message);
    logger.debug ("Error Message Caught >> {} ",message);
    StringBuilder finalErrorMessage= new StringBuilder();
    finalErrorMessage.append (storeMetaData).append (message);

}
```

And client code  throws error as :

```
if (!(requestType.equals ("RF20"))) {
throw new InvalidRequestTypeException 
 (errorData.toString()," Received wrong request type id :" + requestType);}
```

The issue is : The CustomResponseEntity Class always catch Generic Exception ONLY instead of InvalidRequestTypeException ?

Added a log statement inside both handler methods of CustomResponseEntity class and noticed only Generic Exception being called-

```
com.eas.common.exception.framework.CustomizedResponseEntityExceptionHandler 
- CustomizedResponseEntityExceptionHandler-Generic Exception caught !!
 Exception occurred during execution on the exchange:
```

Any suggestions what is missing here ?

Answer (score 1):

Since it was Camel Processor class where I am throwing InvalidRequestType Exception, at the final it gets translated to CamelExecutionException.

Hence it was always falling back to Generic Exception block.